# Formating execvp output

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am working on a shell command program in C, I have it working but the output is not formatted correctly. I am unable to see where the problem lies. I have read through the code several times and I am not seeing the issue. I have tried placing \n in various places but that typicality results in worse formatting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


#define MAX_LINE 80 /*Maximum length of a command*/
#define MAX_HST 10


int main(void){
   char getInput[MAX_LINE];
   char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1]; /*command line arguments*/
   int should_run = 1; /*Flag to determine when to exit the program*/
   int numCommand = 0;
   int cmdHst = 0;
   char *cmdHistory[MAX_HST];
   char *myCmd;
  


   while (should_run = 1){


       printf("osh> ");
       fflush(stdout);


       fgets(getInput, MAX_LINE, stdin);//read input command


      
       if(strcmp(getInput, "!!\n") == 0){//Command history
           if(cmdHst == 0){
               printf("No previous commands.\n");
           }


           for (int i= 0; i<cmdHst; i++){//display all commands in history
               strncpy(getInput, cmdHistory[i], MAX_LINE);
               printf("%s\n", getInput);
           }
       }


       if (cmdHst < MAX_HST){
           cmdHistory[cmdHst] = strdup(getInput);
           cmdHst++;
       }
       else{//shift commands in history to fill gaps
           for(int i = 1; i < cmdHst; i++){
               free(cmdHistory[i-1]);
               cmdHistory[i-1]= strdup(cmdHistory[i]);
           }
           free(cmdHistory[cmdHst-1]);
           cmdHistory[MAX_HST-1] = strdup(getInput);
       }


       //parsing commands into tokens
       numCommand = 0;
       args[numCommand] = strtok(getInput, " \n");
       while(args[numCommand] != NULL){
           numCommand++;
           args[numCommand] = strtok(NULL, " \n");
       }
       args[numCommand]=NULL;


       if(strcmp(args[0], "exit")==0){//Check for exit command
           should_run =0;
           break;
       }


       pid_t pid = fork();//Create child process


       if(pid < 0){
           fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed\n");
           return 1;
       }
       else if(pid == 0){
          
           if(execvp(args[0], args)==-1){
               fprintf(stderr, "Command Not Found.\n");
               exit(1);
           }
           else{
               if(args[numCommand-1][0] != '&'){
                   wait(NULL);
               }
           }
       }    
   }


   for(int i = 0; i < cmdHst; i++){//free histrry array
       free(cmdHistory[i]);
   }


   return 0;


}
```

[image: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TJaZ.png)]

I have read over the code a few times and tried in putting fprintf("\n");s in various places.

Comment: What output is incorrect, and what were you expecting instead? If the issue is the "osh>" appearing on the wrong lines sometimes, that's because you print from multiple processes to the same stream. The output will get mixed unpredictably.

Comment: Looks like you've got the child process waiting. Take a close look at the if/else combinations. `else` is associated with the wrong `if`... (Actually, the child process won't hit that `else` when the execvp is successful...)

Comment: Please edit the image of code into actual text.

Comment: regarding: `while (should_run = 1){`   This is assigning 1 to the loop control variable on every iteration of the loop  >>> so loop will never exit.   Suggest: `while( should_run ) {`

Comment: regarding: `if(cmdHst == 0){
               printf("No previous commands.\n");
           }


           for (int i= 0; i<cmdHst; i++)`   this will try to print the 'history' even thougth though there is none. suggest inserting 'else' before the second `if`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the parent wait(NULL) command. That fixed it.